# Display a JavaScript Popup Box When a Specific Div ID is There

Tags: javascript

I am using an embedded quiz from PlayBuzz.
I made an example here: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50m0avht/)

At the end of each quiz result, I want to display a JavaScript popup box, that says "Thank you!".

Could it be done this way? If this div ID is visible, display the popup.

div ID is `result_screen_container`

Thanks all

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415400/jquery-detecting-div-of-certain-class-has-been-added-to-dom

Comment: I don't get it? @BlueEyedBehemoth

Comment: You're looking for a trigger when a div  with a specific ID gets created in the DOM.