# onLoad of new element, delegate/on?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to run a function on an element (`.this_button`) that is being loaded dynamically. Im using the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("load", ".this_button", function() {
         console.log("its been loaded");
    });
});
```

I tried `delegate`, but it says its been deprecated in  favor of `on`. Some elements might be pushed, say after the document's been loaded for 10 minutes already. How can it continually check if an element `.this_button` has entered the body?

Anyone know why this isnt working?

Comment: Where is it dynamically added?  Can't you just add this function there?

Comment: @rocky No, this element cannot contain a script. Its being loaded from a database and it would complicate things

Comment: Is `}):` really what you have at the end? I assume that should be `});`

Comment: @j08691  Isnt that what .on is for? I tried `delegate`, but it says its been deprecated in  favor of `on`. Some elements might be pushed, say after the document's been loaded for 10 minutes already. How can it continually check if an element `.this_button` has entered the body?

Comment: why are you using the load event if the element is loaded dynamically?  have you tried removing the event? you would be needing to use delegate of course

Comment: I think you can't do that with the `load` event because it doesn't bubble.

Comment: @EH_warch Now we're getting somewhere. When removing `load`, its giving me a typeerror, has no method 'replace'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes):

"In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an  element) do not bubble. [...] Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event."

Comment: What triggers the button to be added to the page? Can you attach it to the same thing?

Answer (score 11):

The `on` method will handle events for the currently selected elements when it is first executed or any future elements that raise a particular event that match a specific selector. Since an element being added to a page does not automatically raise a `load` or some other type of event, your code will never be executed for your newly added elements.

You have two options. The first is to trigger a custom event whenever your new element is being inserted. For instance,

```
$.get("/newElemnet", function(newElement) {
   $('#placeToInsertElement').append(newElement);
   $(newElement).trigger('newElementAdded');
});
```

Then your original function would listen for that custom event:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("newElementAdded", ".this_button", function() {
         console.log("its been loaded");
    });
});
```

The second option is to constantly poll for the new elements as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page).