# html5 audio bind timeupdate before element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

im trying to bind the "timeupdate" event from an audio tag, which doesn't exist yet. I was used to do it this way:

```
$("body").on("click","#selector", function(e) {

});
```

I tried this with the audio tag:

```
$("body").on("timeupdate", ".audioPlayerJS audio", function(e) {
    alert("test");
    console.log($(".audioPlayerJS audio").prop("currentTime"));
    $(".audioPlayerJS span.current-time").html($(".audioPlayerJS audio").prop("currentTime"));
});
```

This doesn't work though. Is this supposed to work? Or what am I doing wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated.

There is a fiddel for you: [jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/Lda9j18f/)

Comment: Looks like the easiest solution would be to declare the event handler after having dynamically added the audio. You can merely detect `timeupdate` on `audio` or `video` (so not on `body`) and `.on('load'` doesn't lend itself for a delegated event, in order to detect when the new audio has loaded. Or just possibly a custom event could be created : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11886423/3168107.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently media events( those specifically belonging to *audio* or *video* like `play`, `pause`, `timeupdate`, etc) do not get bubbled. you can find the explanation for that in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291651/why-dont-audio-and-video-events-bubble).

So using their solution, I captured the `timeupdate` event,

```
$.createEventCapturing(['timeupdate']);  
$('body').on('timeupdate', '.audioPlayerJS audio', updateTime); // now this would work.
```

#### [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lda9j18f/6/)

the code for event capturing( taken from the other SO answer):

```
$.createEventCapturing = (function () {
  var special = $.event.special;
  return function (names) {
    if (!document.addEventListener) {
      return;
    }
    if (typeof names == 'string') {
      names = [names];
    }
    $.each(names, function (i, name) {
      var handler = function (e) {
        e = $.event.fix(e);
        return $.event.dispatch.call(this, e);
      };
      special[name] = special[name] || {};
      if (special[name].setup || special[name].teardown) {
        return;
      }
      $.extend(special[name], {
        setup: function () {
          this.addEventListener(name, handler, true);
        },
        teardown: function () {
          this.removeEventListener(name, handler, true);
        }
      });
    });
  };
})();
```

Comment: I got this error: "Uncaught TypeError: ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function"