# In Shiny DT the focus is lost when there is lot of columns with ScrollX=TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

## TL;DR ?

`scrollX=TRUE` seems bugged but `overflow-x: auto` works in pure css but it's not dynamic (and out of Shiny DT solution).

## edit

March 4,2020: css added for .dataTables_length .dataTables_filter .dataTables_info .dataTables_paginate

## Here is an reprex where the focus of the column is lost and the scroll go back to left

- Run the app,
- go to one of the last colum at right
- Put the pointer in the filter of choosen column to make a search
- => the scroll of DT goes to the left and the column focused has disappeared at right

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
app<-
  shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
      
      fluidPage(
        h3("Home"),
        fluidRow(
          column (12,
                  div(DT::dataTableOutput('outblabla'),
                      style = "font-size:80%;white-space: nowrap;width:1500px")
          )
        )
      )
      
      
    ),
    
    server = function(input, output) {
      
      blabla <-  reactive({
        test<-data.frame(
          matrix (rep(c(c(999.2,2), 1200), 4000), nrow = 40, ncol = 30)
        )
        colnames(test) <-  paste("aaaa_bbbb_ccccc_ddddd_eeee_fffff", 1:30)
        
        return( test
        )
        
      })
      
      output$outblabla<- DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable(blabla(),
                      style = "bootstrap",   class = "compact", filter='top',
                      selection = c("single"),
                      options = list(
                        bSortClasses = TRUE,iDisplayLength = 10,   width = "100%",
                        scrollX=TRUE,
                        autoWidth = TRUE
                      )
        )
      )
    }
  )
shiny::runApp(app)
```

I think it's a bug in DT but I can make a mistake.

## Here is a first workaround with two css solutions,

but it's too large (css 1 int the code) or not dynamic (css 2 in the code), and it's with ScrollX=FALSE...to get scrollX on. The solution 1 is chosen in my real case waiting a good dynamic solution (or a fix in DT if there is a bug).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
app<-
  shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
      
      fluidPage(
        tags$head(
          # 1) too large, it take the # of item and pages Previous/ Next 
          #    but it works with all type of options of DT (with or without # of item by page, smart search, ..)
          tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0(".datatables                       {position: relative; } "))),
          tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0(".datatables  [class^='col-']      {position: inherit;} "))),
          tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0("
                                                   .datatables .dataTables_wrapper   {
                                                         overflow-x: auto;  
                                                         overflow-y: hidden; 
                                                         padding-top: 35px; 
                                                         padding-bottom: 35px;
                                                   }"))),
          tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0(".datatables .dataTables_length    {position: absolute; margin-top: -35px; left:  0px;}"))),
          tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0(".datatables .dataTables_filter    {position: absolute; margin-top: -35px; right: 0px;}"))),
          tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0(".datatables .dataTables_info      {position: absolute; left:  0px;}"))),
          tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0(".datatables .dataTables_paginate  {position: absolute; right: 0px;}"))),
               tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0("
                                                   .datatables .dataTables_wrapper .dt-buttons  {
                                                         left: 150px;
                                                         position: absolute;
                                                         top: 0;
                                                   }"))),    
          # OR
          # 2) It take only the table but it's not dynamic for all type of options of DT
          #tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0(".datatables .dataTables_wrapper .row:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) {overflow-x: auto;}")))
        ),
        h3("Home"),
        fluidRow(
          column (12,
                  div(DT::dataTableOutput('outblabla'),
                      style = "font-size:80%;white-space: nowrap;width:100%;")
          )
        )
      )
      
      
    ),
    
    server = function(input, output) {
      
      blabla <-  reactive({
        test<-data.frame(
          matrix (rep(c(c(999.2,2), 1200), 4000), nrow = 40, ncol = 30)
        )
        colnames(test) <-  paste("aaaa_bbbb_ccccc_ddddd_eeee_fffff", 1:30)
        
        return( test
        )
        
      })
      
      output$outblabla<- DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable(blabla(),
                      style = "bootstrap",   class = "compact", filter='top',
                      selection = c("single"),
                      options = list(
                        bSortClasses = TRUE,iDisplayLength = 10,   width = "100%",
                        scrollX=FALSE,
                        autoWidth = TRUE
                      )
        )
      )
    }
  )
#shiny::runApp(app)
```

## Here is a second workaround, it locates the good `table` element but it doesn't work with many pages in shiny, and it's with ScrollX=FALSE...to get scrollX on.

because the sub element of DT Shiny are not drawn (and `load` event doesn't seem to work with js `delegate`. [I speak about that in github/rstudio/shiny](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2676#issuecomment-583023624). Knowing that from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885425/onload-of-new-element-delegate-on/11885723#11885723) redirecting from [jquery additionnal notes](https://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes)

> "In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an element) do not bubble. [...] Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event."

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
app<-
  shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
      
      fluidPage(
        tags$head(
          HTML(# I want to get event when DT Shiny is drawn, but it's doesn't work for load event
               "<script>
                $(document).on('focusin', '.datatables', function(event) {
                   $(this).find('table.dataTable').closest('div').addClass('div_containing_table');
                }); 
                </script>
               "
          ),
          tags$style(type = "text/css", HTML(paste0(".div_containing_table {overflow-x: auto;}")))
        ),
        h3("Home"),
        fluidRow(
          column (12,
                  p("You have to click on the table to simulate the end of loading of DT, to get scrollx"),
                  div(DT::dataTableOutput('outblabla'),
                      style = "font-size:80%;white-space: nowrap;width:1500px")
          )
        )
      )
      
      
    ),
    
    server = function(input, output) {
      
      blabla <-  reactive({
        test<-data.frame(
          matrix (rep(c(c(999.2,2), 1200), 4000), nrow = 40, ncol = 30)
        )
        colnames(test) <-  paste("aaaa_bbbb_ccccc_ddddd_eeee_fffff", 1:30)
        
        return( test
        )
        
      })
      
      output$outblabla<- DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable(blabla(),
                      style = "bootstrap",   class = "compact", filter='top',
                      selection = c("single"),
                      options = list(
                        bSortClasses = TRUE,iDisplayLength = 10,   width = "100%",
                        scrollX=FALSE,
                        autoWidth = TRUE
                      )
        )
      )
    }
  )
#shiny::runApp(app)
```

Comment: Issue created on github this  Feb 10th 2020 : [github.com/Rstudio/DT#769 In Shiny DT the focus is lost when there is lot of columns with ScrollX=TRUE](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/769)

Comment: css added for .dataTables_length .dataTables_filter .dataTables_info .dataTables_paginate