# jQuery .on() - Element "in document" Event

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I am using jQuery's `.on()` function to attach event handlers to elements when they appear in the document:

```
$(document).on('change', '#elementId', handlerFunction);
```

I would also like to call the `handlerFunction` when the element becomes part of the document, not just when the `change` event is triggered. Is there an event that I can add to the list?

Comment: Couldn't you call the function ina callback of the code that adds elements to the document?

Comment: You can use `Mutation Events` but they are deprecated. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted

Comment: There's an OnDOMNodeInserted event that can be used for this, but it's not cross browser.

Comment: @j08691 - That makes sense, but I can't add a callback there.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page

Answer (score 0):

in your handler function add this line

```
$('#elementId').trigger('change');
```

Comment: I can't trigger the event on a non-existent element. I want a listener that captures the event of the element being added to the document.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function of jQuery:

```
$('#elementId').load(handlerFunction);
```

To paraphrase jQuery's website:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

Comment: The element can be loaded some time after the document is loaded, which is why I am using `$(document).on()`.