# Apply jQuery when new content / markup is added to the page?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, append

I am customising a chat based web interface. I have very limited control over the markup being used.

Basically, I want to add new element `<span class="icon" />` to each chat message.

```
<div id="chatLog">
<span class="msg agent">
  <strong>Agent Name</strong>
  Hi, how are you today? How can I help?
</span>
<span class="msg customer">
  <strong>Customer Name</strong>
  I'm fine thanks, please can you tell me more about the products you sell?
</span>
</div>
```

The jquery I would like to use is something like this:

```
<script>
  jquery('.msg').append('<span class="icon" />');
</script>
```

So I have

```
<div id="chatLog">
<span class="msg agent">
  <strong>Agent Name</strong>
  Hi, how are you today? How can I help?
  <span class="icon" />
</span>
<span class="msg customer">
  <strong>Customer Name</strong>
  I'm fine thanks, please can you tell me more about the products you sell?
  <span class="icon" />
</span>
<div id="chatLog">
```

The markup will be continually changing as more and more messages are sent between the agent and the customer. How can I ensure all chat messages `span.msg` have this new element `<span class="icon" />` appended?

```
<div id="chatLog">
<span class="msg agent"><strong>Agent Name</strong>Hi, how are you today? How can I help?</span>
<span class="msg customer"><strong>Customer Name</strong>I'm fine thanks, please can you tell me more about the products you sell?</span>
<span class="msg agent"><strong>Agent Name</strong>Yes certainly, any particular product?</span>
<span class="msg customer"><strong>Customer Name</strong>Product ISBN-123-456 please</span>
<div id="chatLog">
```

Comment: How are the messages sent?

Comment: So where do you want that `<p>` to be, in the message? And, incidentally, a `p` should *not* be nested within a `span` (that's invalid HTML, I'm afraid).

Comment: Also `span` IDs have to be unique...

Comment: Updated to well formed HTML

Comment: Without knowing what mechanism causes the updates to appear, I don't see how this question can be answered.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake for missing the key info; the DOM is updated by a 3rd party script.

Comment: Does said script provide any events or other mechanism for knowing when a new message appears? If not, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page?lq=1 which simply suggests running a timer to check for new elements. The downside of which is that there will be a short window when the icon hasn't shown up yet.