# Bind an event outside of DOM ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to append a div to all dynamically added divs to my page using this code:

`$('.tagged .post').append('<div class="fadeout"></div>');`

but I simply cannot get it to work. So I was thinking, would it be possible to bind this outside of `$(document).ready()` somehow, so the code looks for all the elements that match the selector and append the "fadeout" div to them?

Comment: you can, but it would have to be after each of these.

Comment: Could you post a complete code example please?

Comment: This code has to be re-ran with each element being added. It won't actively *watch* for new elements and run automatically.

Comment: @DanielA.White: meaning, literally add the script after all the aforementioned divs?

Comment: @Willow yup exactly.

Comment: When are / what causes the DIV's dynamically added?  There must be some event that does this.  You can create custom events to handle your situation but these events would still need to be triggered based on some condition.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Check out this answer: [Event when element added to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page)

Long story short, you have two options:

1. Continually check for the elements
2. Use [Mutation Observers](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-dom-20140508/#mutation-observers)

The answer I linked to above has more details.

Comment: But what if I don't want a click event bound to the element...? How do you code it so the code watches for a dom element being added, and appends the div to it? I don't really have control over the other person's script, so I just need to detect some event that adds the element to the dom.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't quite understand what you were asking. I'll update my answer.