# Trigger javascript/jQuery when element is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the cleanest way of executing something on an element that is dynamically loaded through js/jQuery? Basically the user adds a form that potentially has a wysiwyg editor in it (depending on the context); this is a textarea that needs to have something like `$(".wysiwygTA").editor();` called on it. Of course I could do something like:

```
var newForm = 'some_form_loaded_via_ajax_with_a <textarea class="wysiwygTA"> in_it';
$(".formWrapper").append(newForm);
$(newForm).find(".wysiwygTA").each(function(){ $(this}.editor(); });
```

But that doesnt seem very clean to me. Ideally I want to do something in the fashion of

```
$(document).listenForAddedTextarea(function(textarea){textarea.edtior();});
```

So that I could add the form from multiple places. I *could* isolate the editor-invoke in a seperate function and just call that, but that still leaves me with an extra line of code each time I want to add an element.

**So:** what would be the best way around this? :o)

**Best Regards,**

Rasmus Dencker

Comment: use on() bind dynamically.

Comment: @SuperBear - What would I bind it to? I tried on('[both load and ready]', '.wysiwygTA', ...), but neither works.

Comment: So far the cleanest way I found is including (function(){$(".wysiwygTA").editor(); })(); in the HTML that is loaded via ajax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event when element added to page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `elementAdded` event in JS. Your only option is the 1st one you mentioned. Adding scripts in HTML you are returning from the server is a bad idea IMO.

Comment: I think this answer is sufficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bind method for binding dynamically:

```
 $( document ).bind( "listenForAddedTextarea", function(textarea) {
 textarea.edtior();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer, but the listenForAddedTextarea is actually never triggered, it was just a kind of pseudo-alias for illustrating what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing. Create an event and trigger that event whenever you want.

1. Create an 'listenForAddedTextarea' event like

> ```
> $(document).on("listenForAddedTextarea", function(textarea) {
>  textarea.edtior();
> });
> ```

2. Trigger the event

> $(document).trigger("listenForAddedTextarea");

Comment: What is the point in creating and triggering an event that does not exist? He'll need to call `$(document).trigger("listenForAddedTextarea");` when he loads the HTML from the server. He can just call the function that adds the editor.

Comment: i just replaced this line $(newForm).find(".wysiwygTA").each(function(){ $(this}.editor(); }); from this line $(document).trigger("listenForAddedTextarea");