# Is there a way to delete a certain element from a site using a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So whenever I load up youtube there is always an ad that pops up in the first video slot and I found that if I delete this part of the html: `<ytd-rich-item-renderer class="style-scope ytd-rich-grid-renderer">` using the inspect feature the ad will go away too. Is there a way to automate this with a chrome extension?

Comment: `document.querySelector("ytd-rich-item-renderer.style-scope.ytd-rich-grid-renderer")?.remove()`?

Comment: If you want to remove the ads, i would recommend https://adblockplus.org/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome App/extension to remove a page element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046084/chrome-app-extension-to-remove-a-page-element)