# Select dynamically created html element without click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching around for how to select a dynamically-created (by JQuery) element (in this case, div with class "date"), and keep coming across the .on('click') method. While this works, it seems to only select that div once the page (or containing div #date-container, whichever I have initially) is clicked.

Ideally, right when the .date divs load, I would like to perform some JQuery on them. Is this possible without clicking?

JQuery:

```
$("#date-container").on("click", ".date", function() {
    $('.date').text( $('.date').text().replace('[', '') );
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="date-container"></div>
```

Comment: You only have to wait until the element has been created to act on it with jquery. What you are finding is event delegation, which is a method for adding event handlers to dynamically created elements before they've been added to the DOM (because `$('.date').click(function(){ ... })` only attaches event handlers to the elements currently in the DOM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event when element added to page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page)

Comment: if you create the element dynamically, you should also be able to do whatever you want right after that. Where and how you create the element? give us your code so we can help you further.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
$(document).bind("#date-container", "click", function(){
    // do it to it...
});
```

That should bind the click event to even dynamically-created DOM.

Comment: This seems to still require the user to click for any JQuery affecting the ".date" to be called to action. Am I putting things in the wrong order?

Comment: Isn't there a "load" event?