# Detect when an object is dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How do you detect when an HTML DOM object has come into existence, that is dynamically loaded?

I know what id the element will have, but I don't know when the item will come into existence, i want to empty it and insert something else

This is for a Chrome extension content script.

Comment: Have you tried using a callback after creating this object ?

Comment: It's for a chrome extension, I don't control the other javascipts. Sorry will add that to the question

Comment: How are you "dynamically loading" it?

Comment: Check the duplicate: you are looking to bind an event to modification of the DOM.

Comment: Ok thanks..........

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2844565/218196 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/7434685/218196

Comment: @cruklukukklu -- this answer has the details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14570614/610573

Comment: thanks, that works great!