# How to find the loop iteration done - from outside of the web page with Iframes page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to know when my `iteration` completes from outside of my web page, where my iteration happening inside of a `frame's` child `iframe`

here my example: [Live URL](http://plnkr.co/edit/1QgOJa1zTWV6xysAS6VQ?p=preview) click first button and second button wait 3 sec.

```
$(function(){

  var total = 1000; 
  var i = 0;

  var iterate = function(){

    setTimeout(function(){

      var place = $('#iFrame1').contents().find('#iFrame2').contents().find('body');
      place.append('<ul class="list"></ul>');

      for(i=0; i < total; i++) {
        place.find('.list').append('<li>'+i+'</li>');
      }

    }, 3000);
    //how to find all this done from outside of this function?
  }

  var iFrame1 = $('<iframe />', {id:'iFrame1'});

  var iFrame2 = $('<iframe />', {id:'iFrame2'});

  var button2 = $('<button />', {text:'Child Button', click:iterate});

  var button = $('<button />',
    {
      text:'Click Me',
      click:function(){

        $(this).parents('body').append(iFrame2);

        $('#iFrame1').contents().find('#iFrame2').contents().find('body').append( button2 );

      }

    }
  );


  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.container').append( iFrame1 );
    $('#iFrame1').contents().find('body').append(button);

  },1000);

});
```

After the `place` had all `li`s how to I know from outside of the document. I am running my code from **chrome browser console**.

Answer (score 0):

I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fos52krt/) to attempt to answer this question. Here's what I have done:

1. Added this handler to run when the iteration is complete:

   `var onIterationDone = function() {
               console.log("Iteration Done");
               alert("Done!");
           };`
2. Wired this handler to a custom event `iterationDone` on `button2` right after it's added:

`var button = $('<button />', {
    text: 'Click Me',
    click: function() {
        $(this).parents('body').append(iFrame2);
        $('#iFrame1').contents().find('#iFrame2').contents().find('body').append(button2);
        button2.on('iterationDone', onIterationDone);
    }
});`

3. Fired the custom event as soon as the iteration is done:

   `setTimeout(function() {
               var place =            $('#iFrame1').contents().find('#iFrame2').contents().find('body');
               place.append('<ul class="list"></ul>');
               for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                   place.find('.list').append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
               }

               // Trigger the custom event.

               button2.trigger('iterationDone');
           }, 1000);`

Is this what you wanted to achieve ?

Comment: No this is all wrong. because you are triggering the event from inside of the loop. I don't have any control over the functions. all I need is, I require to hear from outside of the functions.

Comment: I don't understand 'I require to hear from outside of the functions'. What does that mean? The event is triggered when the `for` loop terminates. When and where would you like it to be triggered?

Comment: actually this functions is running inside of a web page( not my web site ), adding my `js` file ( dynamically ) in to that web page i require to add some works, after all this loop done - got me? ( this is customer requirement same domain not CROS issues or anything)

Comment: OK, maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page) might help, you can check the number of `<li>` elements added to the part of the DOM you are interested in and if there are no more updates in a given interval, you can conclude that the updating is finished?

Comment: yes, I require this kind of approach only. for my kind of issue how to handle, since all are inside of Iframe