# Correct way to programmatically fill a ReactJS input

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am building a headless crawler running JavaFX Webkit, it definitely is not as powerful as chrome's v8.

However I've run into problems lately, wherein I am trying to input a value to react rendered input fields.

Here's what I have done till now and failed.[ *Note: I don't have control over the source / React code. Since I am trying to crawl a destination site* ]

1. jQuery - `$('input.r_input').val("2");`
2. Vanila JS - `document.querySelector("input.r_input").value = "2";`
3. Trigger change events through jquery trigger - change, blur , keyup, keydown, etc.
4. Creating a manual event like :

   `event = new Event( event, {target: obj, bubbles: true} );
   event.simulated = true;
   return obj ? obj.dispatchEvent(event) : false;`

and triggering an `input` event.

None of the above works.

I am adding parts of react code from the JS file on the website if it may help to add some more context.

***Create:***

```
t.prototype.createInputProps = function(e) {
    return {
        disabled: this.props.submitting || e > this.focusIndex,
        className: "r_input",
        type: "tel",
        name: "tan-" + e,
        maxLength: 1,
        pattern: "[\\d]*",
        tabIndex: 0,
        placeholder: "·",
        autoComplete: "off"
    }
}
```

***Render :***

```
t.prototype.render = function() {
    var e = this.props,
        t = e.meta,
        n = t.touched,
        r = t.error,
        o = (e.input.value, sa()("r_input", {
            "has-error": r && n
        }));
    return us("article", {
        className: o
    }, void 0, us("div", {
        className: "r_inputs"
    }, void 0, ro.a.createElement("input", as({
        onPaste: this.handleOnPaste,
        ref: this.addInputToList,
        onKeyUp: this.handleKeyUp,
        value: this.getValue(0)
    }, this.createInputProps(0))), ro.a.createElement("input", as({
        ref: this.addInputToList,
        onKeyUp: this.handleKeyUp,
        value: this.getValue(1)
    }, this.createInputProps(1))), ro.a.createElement("input", as({
        ref: this.addInputToList,
        onKeyUp: this.handleKeyUp,
        value: this.getValue(2)
    }, this.createInputProps(2))), ro.a.createElement("input", as({
        ref: this.addInputToList,
        onKeyUp: this.handleKeyUp,
        value: this.getValue(3)
    }, this.createInputProps(3))), ro.a.createElement("input", as({
        ref: this.addInputToList,
        onKeyUp: this.handleKeyUp,
        value: this.getValue(4)
    }, this.createInputProps(4))), ro.a.createElement("input", as({
        ref: this.addInputToList,
        onKeyUp: this.handleKeyUp,
        value: this.getValue(5)
    }, this.createInputProps(5)))), n && r && us(is.a, {}, void 0, r))
}
```

Not sure If I need to add `handleKeyUp`, but that contains some validation code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you by chance have a link to the page you are trying to crawl?

Comment: Sorry that's behind authentication

Comment: OK, I think I was able to provide a good answer any way; hope it helps!

Comment: is there any plunkr, or fiddle that can clarify the issue, so that people can dig right into the code?

Comment: @ProllyGeek Checkout the snippet in my answer, which is pretty much the same as [this codepen](https://codepen.io/quickshiftin/pen/yPGdKo). I think I threw a few more `console.log()` calls in the snippet though.

Comment: @quickshiftin the codepen you mentioned is working!! where is the issue?

Comment: @ProllyGeek, I'm just waiting for OP to try it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, it looks like you can fire a `keyup` event on the element after changing the value. You may also have to wait for the element to appear in the DOM, based on a React state change. Try this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var event = new Event('keyup', { bubbles: true });
    $('input.r_input').val("2")[0].dispatchEvent(event);
}, 3000);
```

It will of course be hard to provide something definitive without access to the page in question.

Note: I came up with the voodoo to dispatch a `keyup` event via [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31056122/680920) which says the React `onChange` handler listens for `input` events and by looking at the code you provided which calls `onKeyUp`. My sample code uses `onChange` handler in React & dispatches `input` events as prescribed in the linked thread.

Also Note: I failed to get this working with jQuery's [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method, maybe you can figure out what I was missing there, but event dispatching with native Javascript is working in my snippet below.

Read on for details!

---

There is no single answer for your question, because how a given React component reads in values from `input` fields can vary, so you'll need to look at each React implementation you are trying to manipulate. I'd hazard a guess that `onChange` is the most common way for React to capture input in a text field. [The React `onChange` handler listens for `input` events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31056122/680920).

It's also possible React's state is updating to cause the elements you are looking for to be added to the DOM after [jQuery's `.ready()` callback](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) fires. This would mean your selectors aren't finding anything because the elements they are looking for are not present in the DOM when they are looking. (This is why I added the `setTimeout` in my suggested solution).

Here I illustrate the issue of elements appearing in the DOM after a React state change, and a working example where jQuery is used to set the value of an `input` element managed by React. (Make sure to look at the console output when you run it to get an idea what's happening), you should see this in the HTML when it's all finished

> React thinks the value is 50

```js
jQuery(function() {
  console.log('jquery loaded');
  
  function searchForNodeOfInterest() {
    console.log('jQuery searching for nodes of interest');
    if(jQuery('#interesting-node').length === 0) {
      console.log('jQuery did not find the selector of interest');
    } else {
      console.log('jQuery found the selector of interest, setting input value...');
      var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
      jQuery('#interesting-node').val(50)[0].dispatchEvent(event);
    }
  }
  
  searchForNodeOfInterest();
  
  setTimeout(searchForNodeOfInterest, 4000);
  console.log('jQuery - taking a nap, I will search again soon...');
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        hidden: true
      };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log('react mounted');
  },
  // Imagine something happens inside react (AJAX response comes in for example),
  // causing the nodes of interest to be rendered in DOM
  componentWillMount: function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('react updating the state...');
        that.setState({
          hidden: false,
          value: null
        })
    }, 2000);
  },
  handleInput: function(e) {
    console.log('react handling input...', e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    return this.state.hidden ? null : <form>React Powered Input: <input type="text" id="interesting-node" onChange={this.handleInput}/><p>React thinks the value is {this.state.value}</p></form>
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="react"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

A more reliable technique than `setTimeout` for some random amount of time is a wrapper that periodically checks for the presence of a selector, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page).

Comment: Thanks @quickshiftin. The devil is in the wait indeed. I was triggering events but not waiting enough, a recursive poll is enough to wait for the event to kick in. I will mark this as accepted.

Comment: Glad to hear that did the trick! And what of the bounty good sir?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to give that :D

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine you simply can't.
It depends how it is implemented and what events it is listening to.

If React Component is controlled and registering 'onChange' event, then it might be possible.

If it's uncontrolled component, then I guess it might not work.
Even if you fill input somehow. On form submit, it might be still using value from it's internal state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 0):

first of all verify that the element exists with a vanilla if. If it exists then programatically fill it it. Note some UI libraries might require an initialization or upgrade upon dynamic add of value.

```
if(document.getElementById("my-input")){
  document.getElementById("my-input").value = "foo";
}
```

If you're adding elements with scripting, you will probably need to attach event listeners after the element is created.