# How to check if more items have been added to the html document

Tags: jquery, html

I'm writing a chrome extension that edits certain reddit posts. Reddit scrolls infinitely, so new posts are continously added. My current solution to this is to run my jquery function once per second. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event when element added to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page)

Comment: if new items appears by scrolling, trigger your function on `Scroll` event. Also if you have complex process on elements, hold the number of target elements in a temporary variable and before repeating the processes, count target elements again.