# Wait for load of all dynamically added images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

After user take action I get related images from server and show to user.
I dynamically insert these images under html element (div).
After all of the images are completely loaded I want to run some script.
Here is my sample code:

```
var images = []; //array of image urls
$(document).on('someEvent', function(){

$.each(images, function(){
    $('#imagesList').append('<li><img src="' + this + '" /></li>');
}); });   
$('#imagesList').on('load', function(){ $(this).show(); });
```

The load event is not firing.
Also, is the load event is right event if some images was cached previously and some was not?

I don't understand how my question can be related to [How can I be notified when an element is added to the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page) this post.

I need to run script after all dynamically added images are loaded within div element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event when element added to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page)

Comment: Have you tried `$("#imagesList").load(function() {`?

Comment: yes this is throwing "Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function" error on "$("#imagesList").load(function() {" this line: https://jsfiddle.net/6rbdmq31/7/

Comment: Can you put attribute or a class to the last created img object?

Comment: If you can put classname to the last created img object, than this script might help you : https://jsfiddle.net/3d7qy49k/

Comment: I guess your code detects change in DOM tree, it will not run when image is loaded, it will run when image is added to DOM. Also last image is not a solution because some of the images loaded at the beginning can have significantly larger size that may cause it is load the last