# How to trigger click after content ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna trigger click on button. But the problem is the click event will always triggered before the button is loaded

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.custom_button').click(function(){
    alert('show');
  });
  $('.custom_button').click();
  $('body').append('<button class="custom_button">abc</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How to do this so the `$('.custom_button').click();` will be trigger whenever the button is loaded into page?

Comment: To be generous, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): why do you want to click a button when the page loads, instead of just calling whatever function is bound to the click?

Comment: you are clicking the button and attaching the event BEFORE you add the button. Your order of actions "On document ready. Bind an event handler to X, Click X, and Create an element X and add it to the page." It is like eating a sandwich before you make it.

Comment: @msanford i can''t describe my real problem its to complicated here but i made a simple case that similar to my problem

Comment: From comments on answers it seems you don't want to change the order of things. That is you want to trigger a click event on an element before it exists... *you can't do that*

Comment: If it's triggering an action when an element is added to the DOM .... again you will face issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page

Comment: From the comments, especially the "I made a simple case" comment - this is not the actual scenario you have, I think simplifying it has hidden the issue.  You appear to be looking to trigger code when the DOM is changed - you might be able to use a Mutation Observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 2):

add `click` event and call it inside `$('.custom_button').ready`.You can call the function after `click` after creating `click` event

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  $('.custom_button').ready(function(){
    
    $(this).click(function(){
       alert('show');
    });
    $(this).click();  
    
  })
  $('body').append('<button class="custom_button">abc</button>');
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i need to do this without changing the order of my code, so the click will always run before button is ready

Answer (score 1):

Move `$('body').append('<button class="custom_button">abc</button>');` line to top inside `$(document).ready` then it will work.

The problem with your code is you are assigning `click` event and triggering it before actually creating that element. So it will not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').append('<button class="custom_button">abc</button>');
  $('.custom_button').click(function(){
    alert('show');
  });
  $('.custom_button').click();      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**With setTimeout**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.custom_button').click(function(){
      alert('show');
    });
    $('.custom_button').click();
  }, 100);
  
  $('body').append('<button class="custom_button">abc</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i need to do this without changing the order of my code, so the click will always run before button is ready

Comment: @Myrealname In simple word I can say it is not possible. Your click event will not trigger if element is not appended yet.

Comment: ya i know it but i have to do this haha

Comment: i've tried this before going here, but it seems like not a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Define the first button generate code, then define click event.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').append('<button class="custom_button">abc</button>');
          $('.custom_button').click(function(){
            alert('show');
          });
          $('.custom_button').click();

        });
```

Comment: i need to do this without changing the order of my code, so the click will always run before button is ready

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and return a Promise from it. Inside the promise resolve method 
create the button, and once it is done use [jquery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger `click`.

Also you need to delegate the event by using `on`

```js
function addButton() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve($('body').append('<button class="custom_button">abc</button>'));
  })

}

$('body').on('click', '.custom_button', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});

addButton().then(function(d) {
  $('.custom_button').trigger('click')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.custom_button', function() {
    console.log('show');
  });
  $('body').append('<button class="custom_button">abc</button>').ready(function() {
    $('.custom_button').click();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just put your html code before any jquery code load. Whenever your DOM is ready with your html content before that trigger function is called.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('body').append('<button class="custom_button">abc</button>');
  
   $('.custom_button').click(function(){
        alert('show');
   });
  
   $('.custom_button').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```